# How to keep one specific key from a nested json object?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following `config.json` file:

```json
{
        "auths": {
                "reg1.io": {
                        "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                },
                "reg2.io": {
                        "auth": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
                },
                "reg3.io": {
                        "auth": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
                }
        }
}
```

I want to keep only the `reg2.io` object to get:

```json
{
        "auths": {
                "reg2.io": {
                        "auth": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
                }
        }
}
```

I can delete one specific object with e.g.:

```json
→ jq 'del(.. | ."reg2.io"? )' ./config.json
{
  "auths": {
    "reg1.io": {
      "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "reg3.io": {
      "auth": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
    }
  }
}
```

but what if i want to keep one specific object? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `select()` with `with_entries()` to select only the key that you want:

```bash
$ jq '.auths |= with_entries(select(.key == "reg2.io"))' file
{
  "auths": {
    "reg2.io": {
      "auth": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    }
  }
}
```

Parametrised so that it takes the wanted key from the command line:

```bash
$ jq --arg key "reg2.io" '.auths |= with_entries(select(.key == $key))' file
{
  "auths": {
    "reg2.io": {
      "auth": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    }
  }
}
```

Change the `==` to `!=` to delete the named key.

Note that your own attempt does not distinguish where the key is found in the document, which could cause some confusion in the general case.

---

Just to add a bit more explanation as to what's happening in the `jq` expression.

Within the `with_entries()` command, what's visible is the following set of objects, each with a `key` and a `value` key:

```json
{
   "key": "reg1.io",
   "value": { "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
}
{
   "key": "reg2.io",
   "value": { "auth": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" }
}
{
   "key": "reg3.io",
   "value": { "auth": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" }
}
```

The `select()` call extracts each object for which the given test is *true*, and discards the rest.  Our test is simply "Is the value of the `key` key the string `reg2.io`?".

A call to `with_entries(expr)` is equivalent to `to_entries | map(expr) | from_entries`.

Comment: Maybe we can think of `with_entries` like SQL `SELECT * FROM '.auths' WHERE '.key' == "reg2.io"`

Comment: @GillesQuénot It's more "meta" than that. It would be equivalent to turning an SQL table into a set of new tables, each with a `key` field that holds a field name from the original table, and a `value` field that holds the corresponding value, and then selecting across those tables. There's no real good equivalent to SQL, unless you start poking around in internal tables holding the actual schemas.  An issue with JSON is that people often use the keys to hold data, as in this case. My solution "fixes" the document (temporarily) by putting all data into _values_ (where it should have been).

Comment: @GillesQuénot (cont.) Putting the data in the keys in JSON is equivalent to creating fields with data as names in an SQL table.

Comment: @GillesQuénot The `select()` call would be the same as your SQL statement though, definitely. To some degree at least (not on `auths` but on a transformed variant thereof).